# Rollback of ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN command taking forever

Tags: sql-server, rollback

I have a very large table that needed a schema change to one column - I needed to expand a datatype from varchar(50) to varchar(100). I expected this to happen quickly since the column datatype is already variable and obviously no data currently in that column would have to change. But after the command ran for several minutes I decided to back away and take another look. Now, after killing the SPID, rollback has been happening for over an hour (much longer than the command had been running). When I run 'kill' with statusonly it says:

SPID 82: transaction rollback in progress. Estimated rollback completion: 0%. Estimated time remaining: 0 seconds.

sp_WhoIsActive shows the wait as IO_Completion.

Why would a rollback on `ALTER TABLE foo ALTER COLUMN bar varchar(100) NULL` get stuck like this? Column bar is varchar(50) now.

Update: rollback finished after about 3 hours. I would still like to know why this took so long to rollback.

Comment: Did the alter column also end up changing column nullability? If just increased length I would have expected that to be a metadata only change that is trivial to roll back

Comment: This alter command did not change nullability. It only increased length. I expected it to be metadata only.

Comment: To avoid a size-of-data operation like this, you would have needed row compression on the table for it to be metadata only.

Comment: @RandolphWest - definitely when I tested this some years back increasing the length of a varchar column was metadata only without row compression (unless increasing it to `max`). Decreasing the length is not as that might fail. Row compression is helpful for cases like changing int to bigint

Comment: And without spending time delving too deeply and just looking at timings I would say this is still the case https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmUCS.png

Comment: Did you do this while the table was being actively used?  Schema locks are required to modify objects, so possibly it was other sessions blocking the attempt.

Comment: @hannah-vernon Good question - yes the table was in use although it is not involved in oltp. But I didn’t check for blockers to the schema lock so can’t say for sure. But if that was causing the delay I wouldn’t have had a three hour rollback right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These links should be helpful in explaining what happens during a rollback:

1. [Rollback: What happens when you KILL a session?](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/03/happens-issue-kill/)
2. [Rollback taking forever](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/189746/150011)

One key thing to takeaway from these is that rollbacks are typically **single-threaded**, which generally contributes to why they can take longer than the query itself was originally running for before the rollback was issued.